# how do i send data to the clicked link in html/java/css

Tags: javascript, html, css

what i need is a system that will let me send some data when a user clicks a link.

for example, if i had an html or javascript file that would display a color depending on data it gets, and the link you click to get there sends the data to that site that determines the color (sets a variable in javascript, or something like that).

i havent tried anything yet since i am new to html and have no idea how to do things that involve interacting scripts. i have looked at github projects with the results i want that use a '#' in the url

Comment: You'd append the data to the URL with something like PHP. So instead of going to website.com, they'd be going to website.com/?color=blue. There is really very many ways to do this, this question is too vague.

Answer (score 1):

You can send the color you want the other site to show in a GET parameter.

E.g, your anchor could look something like this:

```html
<a href="site.com/page?color=red">Red</a>
```

Then, on `site.com/page`, you can use JavaScript to get the `color` parameter value:

```js
const color = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('color')
```